# when i click enter login form should submit in ionic 4

Tags: forms, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-reactive-forms

am developing a web application in ionic. I have a login form. If I click the login button form is submitting and working fine. Now I am looking for after entering the email and password i click enter button then the form should submit. If i click the enter button form should submit. Here is the code.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">    
 <ion-item>
  <ion-input type="email" required class="textWidth" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email id"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
  <ion-input type="password" class="textWidth" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <div class="text-center">
   <ion-button type="submit" (click)="Login()" class="signinButton">Sign in</ion-button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2):

**You can use it**

```
(keyup.enter)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the `(click)="login()"` function to the form like this `(ngSubmit)="login()"`
This should trigger the function on pressing the enter key if there is no other form.

Comment: I have tried this (ngSubmit)="login()", but didn't work.

Comment: Hm maybe i misunderstood you but if I hit enter after I wrote something in the input field the function is called with a console.log 
[Small example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kilby-3eu8b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: But it does not work in *Ionic*